# Assigning a function return as another functions parameter

Tags: python, class

I've got this class and these functions below. Is there a way to assign the return value inside new_number to the parameter number in initial girl constructor?

```
class girl(person):
    def __init__(self, number, interest):
        self.number = number
        self.interest = interest
        super().__init__()
    def new_number(self):
        n = '0000000000'
        while '9' in n[3:6] or n[3:6]=='000' or n[6]==n[7]==n[8]==n[9]:
            n = str(random.randint(10**9, 10**10-1))
        return n[:3] + '-' + n[3:6] + '-' + n[6:]
```

Comment: does `new_number` function have to be inside `Girl` class?

Comment: Er, yes, there is - by calling it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are always going to assign it to `self.number` then don't even accept it as a parameter. Simply call it and assign it:

```
class girl(person):
    def __init__(self, interest):
        self.number = self.new_number()
        self.interest = interest
        super().__init__()

    def new_number(self):
        n = '0000000000'
        while '9' in n[3:6] or n[3:6]=='000' or n[6]==n[7]==n[8]==n[9]:
            n = str(random.randint(10**9, 10**10-1))
        return n[:3] + '-' + n[3:6] + '-' + n[6:]
```

Note that `new_number` can be moved outside of the class as it has nothing to do with it, or it can be made static.

Comment: So dont use it as a paramter, just call it when its needed. Gotcha!

Answer (score 1):

Try this it should be working. you need not to pass number since you are going to call new_number  method.

```
class Girl():
    def __init__(self, interest=0):
        self.number = self.new_number()
        self.interest = interest
        super().__init__()
    def new_number(self):
        n = '0000000000'
        while '9' in n[3:6] or n[3:6]=='000' or n[6]==n[7]==n[8]==n[9]:
            n = str(random.randint(10**9, 10**10-1))
        num_from_new_number = n[:3] + '-' + n[3:6] + '-' + n[6:]
        return num_from_new_number
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just assign the number of `self.number`:

```
class girl(person):
    def __init__(self, number, interest):
        self.number = number
        self.interest = interest
        super().__init__()
    def new_number(self):
        n = '0000000000'
        while '9' in n[3:6] or n[3:6]=='000' or n[6]==n[7]==n[8]==n[9]:
            n = str(random.randint(10**9, 10**10-1))
    self.number = n[:3] + '-' + n[3:6] + '-' + n[6:]   # Assign it here
```

Note that in python, the variable `self` stands for the object itself, so you can manipulate it directly in your class functions.

You can do assignment or initialization like this `self.propertyA = someCalculation()`

Comment: Wow classes are far more friendly in python than in c++